# Why does a vector bundle have the same first Chern class as its determinant bundle?

Tags: vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Let $A$ be a $2n$-dimensional complex vector bundle and $\det A=\Lambda^{2n}(A)$

How is $c_{1}(\det A)=c_{1}(A)$? Here $c_{1}$ means first Chern class.

Comment: If you're OK with mostly formal reasoning, you could argue as follows: If $0 \to S \to E \to Q \to 0$ is a short exact sequence of vector bundles, then $\operatorname{det} E = \operatorname{det} S \otimes \operatorname{det} Q$. Combined with $c(E) = c(S) \cdot c(Q)$ and the splitting principle, you can conclude by induction on the rank. Alternatively, resort to Chern-Weil theory, put a connection on $A$, get an induced one on $\operatorname{det} A$, and do linear algebra to the entries of their curvature tensors until you get what you want.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon I don’t know Chern-Weil theory but I am familiar to axiomatic chern class and property of chern class. Your answer is complete but I don’t understand this part ” if we have the exact sequence of vector bundle $(S,E,Q)$ then we have $\det S \otimes \det Q = \det E.$ “

Comment: It's not by definition, it's something you would need to prove. Picking local coordinates and computing the bundle transition morphisms does the trick.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon thank you for your hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the splitting principle, it suffices to prove this in the case that $A$ is a direct sum of line bundles $L_1\oplus\dots\oplus L_n$.  In that case, we have $$c_1(A)=c_1(L_1)+\dots+c_1(L_n)$$ by the Whitney sum formula, and on the other hand $\det A\cong L_1\otimes \dots\otimes L_n$ so $$c_1(\det A)=c_1(L_1\otimes\dots \otimes L_n)=c_1(L_1)+\dots+c_1(L_n).$$

Comment: Thank you Eric.